# Where do I see the list of newer questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, question-lists

Where do I see the list of newer questions? The main page doesn't seems to show the newer but the questions that have new activities. The "Questions" tab doesn't shows the newer too.

Is very rare to me to find an fresh answer, always it have some views, comments or answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the `Questions` tab, then the secondary `Newest` tab. Voila!

[image]

Comment: =O OMG.. what a dumb I am.. sorry.

Comment: But this list doesn't follow my favorite tags, right ?

Comment: @Márcio - What do you mean "follow"? Your favourites will be highlighted.

Comment: Yes, but the main list seems to show most questions with my tags, almost all questions are highlighted. In this other list no.